# Getting content from useSelector to setState without hitting the backend twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to display a list of names from the back end. I got the page working but it looks like the back end server is hit 2 times instead of expected once to load the list of items on the page. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong here that the server call is made more than once.

```
const Holds = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const names = useSelector(state => state.names);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length === 0) {
        fetchNames();
        setItems(names);
    }
  }, [holds]);


  const renderedList = () => {
    return items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <li>{item}</li>
        )
    });
  }

  return (
       <ul>
           {renderedList()}
       </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: Put `items` in the dependencies of `useEffect` and remove `holds`

Comment: Why did you put names into state .. did you do something else with them ? Why not just ```names.map((item) => { .. })```

Comment: I just posted a part of the code that was relevant. I have to use state here because of checkbox/select all situation that is not shown in the code above.

Comment: Dominik, I tried doing that, but then there is exactly one call as expected but no names would be displayed on the page.

Comment: There is not enough code here.  Your effect runs whenever `holds` changes, but we aren't seeing *where* `holds` changes or even where it is defined.